# How to allow to execute command under root if you are not root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudoers

I want to execute command, file (any file with extension *.sh) from another user except not root user .
I want to provide the file such properly that the another user can execute this file as root user without password.

Answer (score -1):

use `sudo` command befor any command if you want acting as a root

```
sudo mkdir dirname
```

or give full permision to file like it

```
chmod 777 filename
```